# What html markups to use for displaying label/value data?

Tags: html, css, markup, semantic-markup

I want to render a profile user container that contains a list of labels and their associated values.

Here is an excerpt of information and layout I'd like to display:

**First Name**.......MyName

**Age**...................MyAge

**email**................MyEmail

I know that there are tons of examples available but the problem is that it seems that there is no commonly accepted solution.

So far I have seen the following usage :

1. Table with  markup (and < tr >,< td >...)
2. Unordered list with < ul > markup (and < li >, < div >...)
3. Regular markups with < h1 >,< h2 >...< p >
4. Definition List with < DL >, < DT > and < DD >
5. < label >...?

What is the most semantically correct? What is the easiest to display (in a 2-columns layout)? What do you advise me to use and for what reasons?

(html/css code snippets are more than welcomed)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wow. We really have scared everyone off with the “Table layouts are evil! Use CSS!” stuff, haven't we?

A table — with `<th>` for the labels and `<td>` for the values — is perfectly applicable to this kind of content, gives you the rendering you want, and is at least as semantically correct as a definition list, arguably more so. Either are preferable to semantics-free divs.

Comment: So true!  Really, if your data is tabular, put it in a table. That's what they're for.

Comment: It could be argued that this isn't a table of data, but a list of labels and values.  If there were more values then it would definitely be a table

Comment: In my situation, there is indeed more values. But I don't understand your comment. According to you, with few items, this is a list of labels/values but when the number of items is over a certain threshold, it becomes a table????  Do you limit your usage of  unordered list (<ul>) according to the number of items?

Comment: I'll try to clear up the confusion. When there are more values...e.g. First Name.....MyName, AnotherName, etc (e.g. rows of data) then it is a table of data.  The code above is clearly just a list of labels / values.

Comment: @John. Again, 3 items of label/value pair or 100, what is the difference? I have understood your point but I don't think that it is logical to treat data differently if you have either 3/4 items or 10 items. Or maybe, in both case, you would have used a <table> but naming the data differently?

Comment: @fabien. I think you have missed my point. I'm trying to say when a label has multiple values then you should be using a table. In this case where the label/value is a one-to-one relationship then really a dl is more appropriate. Even if the list was a 100 items long.

Comment: Both a table and a definition-list would be fine here; it's largely a matter of taste. Some three-column tables could also be presented as a definition-list with two dd elements per dt element, and indeed there are examples like this in the HTML specifications. The rule I usually go by is that I use a definition-list if the number of definitions per term is varied - for example, some words in a dictionary will have multiple meanings, so a definition-list is appropriate. In fabien's case, I'd use a table if the data was as shown, but if a user could have two email addresses I'd use a list.

Comment: @John. I got your point and I agree with you. 

@Chris. That is a good rule of thumb that I will try to apply. Thx.

Comment: yes, tables are almost always a bad idea, and this is no exception imho. Just add another field, say `message` that can contain a text with 255 length. Now it should be responsive as well. Where does your table go now? yes, out the door.

Answer (score 40):

I think the most semantically correct would be `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>`, since what you're displaying are effectively *definitions* of first name, age and e-mail.

```html
<dl>
  <dt>First Name</dt>
  <dd>Dominic</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd>24</dd>
  <dt>E-mail</dt>
  <dd>foo@bar.com</dd>
</dl>
```

However, obviously, the easiest way to display it in a table is using `<table>`, `<th>` and `<td>`. You could hack together a table-layout using definition lists using something like this:

```css
dt { float: left; clear: left; width: 6em; font-weight: bold; }
dd { float: left; }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>First Name</dt>
  <dd>Dominic</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd>24</dd>
  <dt>E-mail</dt>
  <dd>foo@bar.com</dd>
</dl>
```

More info on the `<dl>` tag available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl).

Comment: Are you sure that it is the most semantically correct? according to what I have been reading, <dl> is used for definition/description pairs (for glossary for instance) which is not the same as label/value pairs.

Comment: I suppose it depends what your definition of "definition" is. For example, in the context of me, my first name is defined to be "Dominic". Whether you think that is a valid use of the word "define[d]" or not is somewhat subjective.

Comment: According to the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.3), DL can be used to more than "definitions". The list type is intended for use as a list of key-value-pair (or multiple values) type of list.

Comment: This article (http://www.benmeadowcroft.com/webdev/articles/definition-lists.shtml) gives examples of <dl> usage using only terms/descriptions pairs. It says "definition lists are important because they provide a context for the text with which they are associated". Clearly, you define a term once and that's all. For instance, this is a genuine usage: <dt>CSS</dt> and <dd>Cascade Style Sheet</dd> because the value side of "CSS" is not supposed to change for each user contrary to the label "First Name"

Comment: <dl> has been rebranded as a description list in the latest [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110405/dl.html#dl). It seems to clarify that name / value pairs are appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been answered but I think definition lists can be perfectly appropriate.
I do agree with the **bobince** that tables are always appropriate for tabulated data...
However I have used this in a number of places where I preferred to avoid tables - and I don't think it is an incorrect method.

Definition lists:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Label</dt>
  <dd>Value</dd>

  <dt>Label 2</dt>
  <dd>Value 2</dd>
</dl>
```

With the CSS:

```
dl dt {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
}

dt dd {
  margin-left: 215px;
}
```

Comment: This was useful to me. I believe there's a typo. The CSS should be: dl dt {...} and dl dd {...}

Comment: fixed the typo :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a good question and is also one that is open to much debate becasue there is no fixed way of doing this.

there are arguments for many of them but me personally, I would keep it simple.

```
<div class="profile">
    <p>
        <span class="label">First Name</span>
        <span class="value">MyName</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Age </span>
        <span class="value">MyAge</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Email</span>
        <span class="value">MyEmail</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

or

```
<ul class="profile">
    <li>
        <span class="label">First Name</span>
        <span class="value">MyName</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="label">Age </span>
        <span class="value">MyAge</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="label">Email</span>
        <span class="value">MyEmail</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS would look something like this;

```
.profile p {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.profile .label {
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

.profile .value{
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
```

the reason for not referencing any specific html Node name in the CSS is that if in the future there is a recognised way of doing this you only have to change node names in your HTML.

Comment: A bad solution in my opinion. You never define anywhere - semantically - that the labels are labels, which are connected to the values. For anything else than a normal web browser (screen readers, mobile devices etc) the text in each paragraph would just look like "First Name Myname", "Age Myage" etc. - which is just not very readable.

Comment: Try to avoid using the p tag for things that aren't really paragraphs.

Comment: This isn't semantically correct.  P tags are for paragraphs and there is no definition of what is a label and what is a value

Comment: Maybe it is not the correct answer. However it is a widespread usage AND it should not be downvoted ! Downvote is usually ofr answers that are out-of-scope or totally wrong !

Comment: Widespead usage does not make answers correct.  A while ago table based layout had widespread usage, that didn't make it correct. I'm sorry, but this markup is totally wrong.

Comment: Maybe then a `UL` is semantically better, I have added the case. I don't believe that a `DL` is correct, but I would accept a table with `TH` used for the labels. As far as I know the `LABEL` element is for associating text with form elements and is part of the W3C form spec?

Comment: I also believe that the DL is not correct according to the different articles/examples I have read so far. Your second solution seems acceptable. What do other folks here think ?

Comment: @John. I do not discuss the fact that the answer might be wrong (maybe better with the new edit?) but why people downvoting this answer ? Anyway, I might be wrong because I have found this (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21080/why-are-people-afraid-of-downvotes) that basically explain that we should not be so afraid of downvoting. But personally, I downvote only when the answer is inappropriate